# PHP: is there any case in which "include_once" resets the stack?

Tags: php, php-include

Say I have this code:

```
class control {
  function public_home()
    {
        $pagina=$this->load_public_page();
        ...
        echo $pagina;
    }

...
        function load_public_page($localnode="") {

            global $language;

            if ($localnode != "") { $localnode="_" . $localnode; }

            $langlink = "http://" . PAGE_INDEX;
            if ($language != "es") { $langlink = $langlink . "/" . $language . "/"; }

            ob_start();
            include_once 'page.php';
            include_once 'header.php';
            $pagina=ob_get_contents();
            ob_end_clean();
            return $pagina;
            }
...
}
```

And then, in `page.php`:

```
<?php
echo "LANG " . $langlink;
echo "NODE " . $localnode;
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
...
```

`page.php` should be able to access both `$langlink` and `$localnode` variables without problems, right? (I have tried with a simplified example and it does work). Well, in my case it doesn't; no matter how I try, the code in page.php says that `$langlink` and `$localnode` are undefined.

Not only that: if I add a `var_dump(debug_backtrace())` to `page.php`, it will show me only:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["file"]=>
    string(53) "index.php"
    ["line"]=>
    int(55)
    ["function"]=>
    string(12) "include_once"
  }
}
```

In other words, it doesn't pick up neither the `load_public_page` function, not its containing class... No wonder it can't find those variables.

It's extremely odd, because look at the simplified example I mentioned above:

```
class Ble {
    function bla() {
        $a=127;

        $pagina=$this->otrosi();
        echo $pagina;
        }

    function otrosi($bbb="") {

        $a=666;

        ob_start();
        include_once('b.php');
        $pagina=ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();

        return $pagina;
        }
    }

$g=new Ble();   
$g->bla();
```

Where `b.php` is:

```
<p>BBB is: <?php echo $bbb; ?></p>

<p>What is A? <?php echo $a; ?>
```

It does print `$a` as `666`, as it should, and of course, if I add a `debug_backtrace` in `b.php`, it shows me the full stack trace: `object Ble, function bla, function otrosi`....

As the title says: does anyone know of any circunstances in which an `include_once` or output buffering might reset the stack in PHP? I'm a bit desperate, because this is one of those things where, according to docs and simple examples, it SHOULD work... and yet it doesn't.

Comment: `include` acts as if the contents of the file you're including were literally cut/pasted into the spot where the `include()` call is. that's all. if you "executable" code inside that file, then it will get executed, but in the context of where the include() is. if there's an exit/die in that file, then the entire script exits, not just just the included file. what you can't do is spread object definitions between multiple files. http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php   read the final paragraph of the opening blurb.

Comment: please dont use register globals :( they are totally evil. objects and namespaces are your friend. globals can cause all kinds of havoc with debugging!

Comment: where doe he use "register globals" ?

Comment: @steve: I should mention that I didn't write this code, I'm just stuck with mantaining it. Anyway, I don't see how that global variable I used (NOT "register_globals") is relevant to the bug I've found.

Comment: @Marc B: I know, I've read the docs. That's how it's supposed to work, and that's how it works in the simple example I provided :-). Which makes it even more baffling when the actual code doesn't work. I don't see where I spreaded the object definition, though: I have a "control" object in one file, and inside it, in the "load_public_page" function, I `include` the `page.php` file and capture its contents with output buffering. That's all.

Comment: And where in your code is `$control->load_public_page(...)` called?

Comment: @JensA.Koch: I've edited my question to add that code. I should repeat: I wasn't the original author of this code, just the mantainer.

Comment: Ok. What happens if you simply comment out the include_once statements? What happens if you simply add an `echo 'Called load_public_page';` as first line of that function? ... In other words: can you make sure that `$control->public_home()` and `$control->load_public_page(...)` are executed? If you have xdebug, simply add a breakpoint..

Comment: Sure, they are being executed. `page.php` is being included from inside `load_public_page`, so if it wasn't executed, it wouldn't be included at all. What's more: if I add an `echo $langlink`right before the `include`, it prints the value of the variable correctly. And if I make up another file and include it after `page.php`, i.e.: `include "test.php"`, and try accesing the variables from it, it works.